# Get subarray from 2D Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of arrays

```
-Array1 
 [0]+ SubArray1.1   
    + SubArray1.2   
 [1]+ SubArray2.1   
    + SubArray2.2
```

I want to extract SubArray1.2 ,SubArray2.2 ... i.e. 2nd index of each Row and store it in different collection.

this is my jsfiddl: http://jsfiddle.net/gkVyC/1/

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 var Newcollection=[];

 $.each(Array1, function (index, value) {
     Newcollection.push(value[1]);
 });
```

Newcolletion return undefined . I have seen `slice()` method, but example was with one dimensional Array. I'm not able to implement it in my case.

Comment: Your code looks right to me. What does "not working" mean? an error? Not what you expect in `Newcollection`?

Comment: Newcolletion return array with all Rows as undefied

Comment: If `Newcollection` is blank then your `Array1` was blank (or not really an array)

Comment: For future reference, you should use proper terminology instead of "blank". We don't know whether you mean `[]`, `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Newcolletion return array with all Rows as undefied

Comment: Look - here is exactly your code and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/gkVyC/

Comment: In your case 2nd element is a number  ..but in my case 2nd element is an subarray ..which I m not able to extract

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle in code ...

Comment: @user3767164 check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var subarray= [];
for(var i = 0; i<yourarray.length; i++) {
   subarray.push(yourarray[i][1]); //1 for 2nd element
}
return subarray;
```

**Update**

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/gkVyC/4/)

There were two mistakes in your fiddle

1) you are pushing twice `array1` in your `Array`

```
   Array.push(Array1)
   Array.push(Array1)
```

2) you are looping using `Array1` instead of `Array`

```
$.each(Array1, function (index, value)
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the OP code, just without `$.each`

Comment: Jamiec No it isn't, it says `var subarray= [];` which OP forgot.

Comment: subarray return array with all Rows as undefied ..same as my result .. I Edited the Code

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/TwKf4/

**JS**:

```
var input = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]];
var output = Array();
for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)
{
    if(input[i][1])
        output.push(input[i][1]);
}
console.log(output);
```

Here is your fiddle updated with desired output:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkVyC/5/

JS:

```
var Array = []
var Array1=[]
var Array2=[]

Array1.push(1.1)
Array1.push(2.1)
Array2.push(1.2)
Array2.push(1.2)


Array.push(Array1)
Array.push(Array1)

console.log(Array);

var Newcollection =[];
for(var i=0;i<Array.length;i++)
{
    if(Array[i][1])
        Newcollection.push(Array[i][1]);
}

for(var i=0;i<Newcollection.length;i++)
   alert(Newcollection[i]);
```

Comment: Why have you given an example with an extra level of array nesting? That adds potential for confusion without gaining anything.

Comment: array is nested in my case ...this solution is not working for subarray .I have updated the JSFiddle ...

Comment: dude just share your input and expected output, you will get a definite solution. Mat be you want the second array of every element in n level of sub nesting. Please provide i/o or updated fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Are `Subarray1` etc actual arrays, or objects whose keys are stringified numbers? From what you said at the start it looks like they're `{1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}`, in which case the keys are the strings `'1'` and `'2'`. But later on you try to access them as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're putting your array-of-arrays into a variable `Array`, but then looping over `Array1`:

From your fiddle:

```
var Array = []
var Array1=[]
var Array2=[]

Array1.push(1.1)  // you're looping over this one
Array1.push(2.1)
Array2.push(1.2)
Array2.push(1.2)

Array.push(Array1) // but they're in here
Array.push(Array1) // and this one should be pushing `Array2`
```

Here is your fiddle, updated to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gkVyC/2/